# Dynamically grouping jenkins job results

Tags: jenkins

I've had a dig around but can't find an elegant solution for what I want to do, so I hope some of you may be able to offer some suggestions. I've also asked this question on a jenkins forum, but no takers.

I want to be able to run a jenkins parent job with parameters that will feed down to triggered jobs, and **then group all the job run results** in a view dynamically.

The use case I'm trying to cover is: We have 10+ different jenkins jobs that run suites of tests, I want to simply manage a run of all those jobs to run against a specific code branch, on a specific test environment, and see the results (in one view) for only that run. The complication is the same Jenkin job may be run against another release or test environment and I don't want to see those results.

We already have the parent job triggering children with parameters, but I can't figure out how best to group the results.
I know I can create filters for views, but the name of jenkins jobs is static, and I want the view created at runtime, without having to build it myself. We do use the 'Set Build description' Plugin, so I could create a view that filters for a unique build descriptor, or something similar. But there doesn't seem to be a way to create views with filter programmatically.

Other considerations would be clean up. I wouldn't want a years worth of views clogging the views, so I need a way to clear out old runs too.

Any ideas to kick me off?

Comment: Do you want to group the results of several different suite executions in a single report? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For groupping of reports you can just use a simple logic instead of finding a Jenkins plugin. You can place all the result files (preferably XMLs) in a common folder/ file server and at the end of execution of all the suites (jobs) you can trigger a common job which will process all the XML files and generate a common report. By this you can have " consolidated + individual reports ".
I have done it using Perf Publisher plugin which process XMLs and gives a beautiful aggregated report.

Job1 ----> Report1 ----> Move report of report folder

Job2 ----> Report2 ----> Move report of report folder

Job3 ----> Report3 ----> Move report of report folder

.

.

.

Job n ----> Report n ----> Move report of report folder

So after completion of job n, trigger Report job which will operate on "report" folder containing all the reports!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for that idea, Unfortunately it doesn't capture enough of what I want. We create a lot collateral during a run that I want to also have grouped at the end of a batch run, not just a report.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution:
All jobs accept a parameter called VIEW_IDENTIFIER. 
Parent job is kicked off with a unique VIEW_IDENTIFIER being set, and all the child jobs have that passed into them when run.
After all jobs are run I edit a Jenkins View that has a 'Job Filter - > Parameterized Jobs Filter - > Name = VIEW_IDENTIFIER, Value = my unique ID set for the run'

This results in all jobs run with that unique ID being grouped in one single view for review.

The shame is I have to do the manual edit of the Job Filter.